# Corner making a tri face

Tags: modeling

On the edge of my model I'm trying to eliminate the tri face it's making. If I do a knife cut vertical, it'll make a quad, but if I go horizontal it'll make a tri face. When I add the subdivision modifier, it seems like a much cleaner topology. Is there a solution when it comes to avoid the mesh from making a tris?

[image]

Comment: I don't have a answer for that specific case, but the whole Topology Guides are a must-read and should give you some directions : https://topologyguides.com/archive/

Comment: Suggest add another **support edge on the side** (which is needed for the subsurf anyway) and I think the problem might goes away automatically... see [Jachym's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199492/31447).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the knife cut at all :).

Just inset the corner slightly, it'll move the ugly quad out of the way.
The corner is now smooth, and you can add more loopcuts to make it sharper.

[image]

Comment: A link to eg. https://topologyguides.com/ or https://graphics.pixar.com/opensubdiv/docs/mod_notes.html might be useful.

Comment: Oh, that pixar page is a new one for me, thanks :).